# EKEventStore eventsMatchingPredicate assigning value

Tags: ios, cocoa

I am having problems storing the events from an EKEventStore query. For instance when using the following code, *events* is always nil:

```
__block NSArray *events = [[NSArray alloc] init];

if ([eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)]) {
    [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (granted)
                events = [eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];
        });
    }];
}
```

I know that [eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate] is returning events as if I put a NSLog inside the block then I can see the event details. It seems like there is a problem with retaining the result. As you can see I have tried doing it on the main thread with no avail.

I am using ARC which might make a difference.

Thanks

Comment: You're assigning an allocated NSArray to the `events` variable, then you're re-assigning that to an array returned bt the `eventsMatchingPredicate:` call, which is meaningless and leaks memory. This is not `memcpy()`...

Comment: I assume you mean eventsMatchingPredicate rather than requestAccessToEntityType? Even if I I don't alloc events, and just declare it as nil I still have the same issue. Plus I am using ARC so surely it would put in the required release for me.

Comment: yes, that's it, sorry...

Comment: To work around this, you might try making `events` mutable, then using `addObjectsFromArray:` to get the EKEvent instances into it. (I think you can drop the `__block` qualifier that way as well.)

Answer (score 1):

Sure.. What I meant was that i was doing 'return events' after my requestAccessToEntity block. This is no good as it will return straight away as the requestAccessToEntity block is asynchronous and take a short while to perform that action. So I made a delegate and call this delegate once requestAccessToEntity is complete so it notifies me when it is done, and passes back the array in the delegate call.. Something like this:

```
[eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if (granted) {
        if (delegate != nil && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(todaysEventsComplete:)]) {
            events = [eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [delegate todaysEventsComplete:events];
            });
        } else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [UIAlertView alertViewWithTitle:nil message:@"You have denied access to your calendar for this app"];
            });
        }
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out.

I was performing the above code in a method that returned the NSArray events. Now the problem is that `requestAccessToEntityType` is performed asynchronously. So even though in the block itself I was updating the array on the main thread, by this point it was too late as the method would have already returned.

Had to change it so it now has a delegate that returns the events once it has finished doing its thing.